# Terraform unknown module referenced:

Tags: terraform

root/main.cf

```
module "vpc_dtap" {
    source = "../modules/aws-vpc-dtap"

}


module "aws-ec2-instance-domain-controller-server" {
    source = "../modules/aws-ec2-instance-domain-controller-server"

}
```

root/multi-domain-controller-servers/main.cf

```
module "ec2_instance_domain_controller_servers" {
  source = "D:/Users/user/terraform/modules/aws-ec2-instance-domain-controller-server"


  ### Instance Name and AMI
  instance_names = "${var.ec2_instance_domain_controller_server_names}"
  ami            = "${lookup(var.ami_windows_base, var.region_name)}"

  ### Tags
  env_name      = "${var.env_name}"
  global_tags   = "${var.global_tags}"
  instance_tags = "${var.ec2_instance_domain_controller_server_instance_tags}"

  ### VPC Data
  vpc_id             = "${module.vpc_dtap.vpc_id}"
  availability_zones = "${module.vpc_dtap.availablity_zones}"
}
```

and getting:module 'ec2_instance_domain_controller_servers': unknown module referenced: vpc_dtap

How to reference vpc_dtap module to aws-ec2-instance-domain-controller-server module ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating vpc.tf under root/multi-domain-controller-servers

```
module "vpc_dtap" {

  source = "D:/Users/user/terraform/modules/aws-vpc-dtap"

  global_tags = "${var.global_tags}"

  ### Parameters ###
  # CIDR block of the VPC. This block will be used as a base for all subnet ranges.
  cidr_block = "${var.cidr_block}"

  # Currently the VPC module supports only 2 availablity zones.
  availability_zones = "${var.availability_zones}"

  # The environment name is used all over the place as a prefix to all VPC specifics, subnets , route tables, etc.
  env_name = "${var.env_name}"

  # The domain name is used for the DHCP option set.
  domain_name = "${var.domain_name}"
}
```